# Issues with Mouse Cursor Shape made with ‘Afterimage’ Post-processing filter

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I’ve been working on implementing a custom cursor at the top of my scene by utilizing the ‘Afterimage’ post-processing filter. While I’m not entirely sure if this is the right approach, I decided to give it a try. My aim is to display the ‘afterimage’ in a circular shape around my mouse cursor. I’ve managed to make it work to some extent, but I’m facing problems in achieving a perfectly circular effect.

so I tried to modify the shader in this way:

```
’void main() {’,
```

’ vec4 texelOld = texture2D( tOld, vUv );‘,
’ vec4 texelNew = texture2D( tNew, vUv );’,

```
'   float distance = distance(vUv, mouse);', // I take the distance between the pixel and the mouse cursor but of course I should find a way to have something like distance.x and distance.y*screenratio to have a perfect circle. but I don't find the way top do it

'   if (distance < radius) {', // so  effect is applied to all pixels within the radius
'       texelOld *= damp* 1.2* when_lt( texelOld, 0.4 );',
'          //texelNew*= damp* 1.2* when_lt( texelOld, 0.3 ); ',

'    } else {',

'        texelOld *= damp * 0.1 * when_lt( texelOld, 0.9 );',
'    }',
'   gl_FragColor = max(texelNew, texelOld);',

'}'
```

on the image you can see the shape of the cursor (bottom middle) which is pretty ugly, I tried so many ways to change the conditions in the shader that it could display the right shape. thanks for help.

[image]